# Type Mismatch : cannot convert from Int to ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, compiler-errors

```
public ResultSet updateSql(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
    return sta.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

This is fuction in listener conn

but error in listener

```
return sta.executeUpdate(sql);
```

> Type Mismatch : cannot convert from Int to ResultSet

Comment: have you checked what "executeUpdate" returns?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: The title of your post is really hard to read and will throw off potential answerers. Please fix the spelling/language mistakes and make it a clear, concise title, it will help you get answers.

Comment: In the future when you get an error, simply copypaste it in a search engine to check if it isn't already asked and answered before, [like so](https://google.com/search?q=Type+Mismatch+%3A+cannot+convert+from+Int+to+ResultSet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return sta.executeUpdate(sql);
```

This returns the number of rows affected after the query is executed such as (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) i.e. the return type of executeUpdate() is integer. This will not return any resultset. ResultSet is used when query such as SELECT query is used i.e. when you have to pull the rows from the table. After pulling from the table it is place in the ResultSet for further process in java.

This is why the error is showing:

```
Type Missmatch : cannot convert from Int to ResultSet
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer btw, It's working several minutes ago.

Comment: Glad that helps. Also dont forget to check the answer if it helps. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public int updateSql(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(toString(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    return preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```